# Undesirable popup in datepicker in IE6

Tags: jquery, date, internet-explorer-6, jquery-ui-datepicker

I am using a datepicker for one of my form elements in my Drupal page.

The problem i have is that in IE6 (testing in IE7 and Firefox, it looks fine),
there is a box below the calendar with the word false in it.

When the first date picker is clicked, the box is the same size as the
calendar. When another date picker is clicked on the same page the
false box is twice as big.  The box continues to grow in size every
time a date picker is clicked.

[image]

Included the screenshot of the issue.... i see that an iframe is being added.
Dont understand what could be the issue and how to fix it.

Comment: Maybe a little side note...but why you still even test in IE6? About 2% of the users still use IE6.

Comment: It is recommended to use the latest version of jquery.bgiframe-2.1.1.js

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add this to your css

```
iframe.ui-datepicker-cover { display:none; }
```

else try this

```
.ui-datepicker-cover {
  display: none; /*sorry for IE5*/
  display/**/: block; /*sorry for IE5*/
  position: absolute; /*must have*/
  z-index: -1; /*must have*/
  filter: mask(); /*must have*/
  top: -4px; /*must have*/
  left: -4px; /*must have*/
  width: 193px; /*must have to match width and borders*/
  height: 200px; /*must have to match maximum height*/
}
```

Reference [here](http://old.nabble.com/Date-Picker-in-IE6-has-%22false%22-box-td18506634s27240.html)

Comment: Thanks, i tried to include that code in ui.datepicker.css in the default theme of my jquery.ui. But the problem persists.

Comment: Add it like this `iframe.ui-datepicker-cover { display:none !important; }`

Comment: I already have the above css for: **ui-datepicker-cover** in my **ui.datepicker.css**. Also included this style in **datepicker.1.7.css**. But does not solve my problem in ie6.

Comment: Oh my goodness, solved my problem after a small hack. I put those 2 css statements in a separate css file and included that file in my page. Surprised to see that there is no iframe anymore in ie6. Thanks a lot. :)